# UDP packets received internally but not externally - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: iptables, udp, ufw

thanks in advance for taking a look at this... I'm confident that the solution is simple - it's just I don't know what it is.

Running `nc -l -u 9090` AND `nc -uv 82.165.109.4 9090` command on the same server, establish a netcat type "connection" and messages are received as expected.

There is a docker application running that also receives the packet so it looks like the internal environment is setup alright.

`echo -p "hello" >/dev/udp/82.165.109.4/9090`

is received by both `tcpdump` and the application.

---

I'm monitoring receipt of the packets with:

```
tcpdump -i any udp -AXn port 9090
```

- If I send a UDP packet from outside the box, it doesn't reach `tcpdump`
- I cannot ping the server externally, but can internally.
- The port appears to be open and listening.
- the ssh, http and https ports are all functioning as expected.

```
netstat -ltu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5984            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9070            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:https           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:5984               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:9070               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootpc          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 [::]:9090               [::]:*
```

---

Everything I have read points to `iptables` and the firewall, so I disabled `ufw`

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.3           udp dpt:9090
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.6           tcp dpt:9080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:5984
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

The NAT settings are as follows:

```
iptables -t nat -L -v -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 235 packets, 28704 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  163  9840 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 205 packets, 26904 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 72 packets, 5351 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   121 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 108 packets, 7416 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    4   240 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !br-a371a521a463  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       172.18.0.3           172.18.0.3           udp dpt:9090
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.18.0.6           172.18.0.6           tcp dpt:9080
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.18.0.2           172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:443
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.18.0.5           172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:5984
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.18.0.2           172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   120 RETURN     all  --  br-a371a521a463 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1    37 DNAT       udp  --  !br-a371a521a463 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:9090 to:172.18.0.3:9090
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !br-a371a521a463 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9070 to:172.18.0.6:9080
    4   220 DNAT       tcp  --  !br-a371a521a463 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 to:172.18.0.2:443
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !br-a371a521a463 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5984 to:172.18.0.5:5984
    5   248 DNAT       tcp  --  !br-a371a521a463 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:172.18.0.2:80
```

If UFW was enabled the status is:

```
ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (high)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
993                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
995                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
9090/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
520/udp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
993 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
995 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
9090/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
520/udp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             

9090/udp                   ALLOW FWD   Anywhere                  
9090/udp (v6)              ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6)
```

I've tried a lot - but some of the more important things are;

- flushing the iptables had no effect
- monitoring the UDP send via tcpdump from the external box (which was logged)
- monitoring all ports and verbose logging (no change)
- switching on ip_forwarding

```
sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

---

Other notes:

- Using a 'cloud' server, therefore a virtual machine.
- I cannot find any ufw logs in `/etc/ufw/`